# satellite imagery basemap for webmapping application

Tags: coordinate-system, web-mapping, imagery, basemap, web-mercator

I am currently trying to develop a small webmapping application to show some point data which covers the whole planet. 
I do want to use projections different from webmercator, like Robinson projection, for example. 
Additionally, I want to use a satellite imagery basemap. 
 The Problem is that almost all the ready-to-use (satellite imagery) map tiles are webmercator projected. 
I have found (here in this forum) just one provider offering tiles in projections different from webmercator: https://earthdata.nasa.gov/about/science-system-description/eosdis-components/global-imagery-browse-services-gibs
But the projections used there are not these that i do need.

How can i add a satellite imagery basemap with projections different from webmercator?

Comment: Please focus your question to one question instead of multiple questions.

Comment: You can download BlueMarble as GeoTiff and reproject it (e.g. using gdal or qgis) to your needs: https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=BlueMarbleNG-TB&date=2004-06-01 ----- or if you need higher resolutions: https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view_cat.php?categoryID=1484

Comment: OpenLayers will reproject the basemap for you - https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/raster-reprojection.html